# PHP 5.3 seems to be missing Intl extension by default

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, icu, intl

My system is Ubuntu 12.04, PHP 5.3, and I'm trying to run some basic Intl code like this:

```
<?php
$coll  = collator_create('en_US');
$result = collator_compare($coll, "string#1", "string#2");
```

and it outputs

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function collator_create()
```

Wasn't Intl extension supposed to be bundled with PHP since version 5.3?

PHP was installed via `apt-get` with this command line (I don't use Apache):

```
apt-get install php5 php5-cli php5-mysql php5-cgi php5-fpm php5-curl php-apc php5-memcache php5-memcached php5-common php5-gd php-xml-parser php-pear php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-xdebug php5-suhosin
```

And here is what `php -v` produces:

```
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.5 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jan 18 2013 23:40:19) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by Derick Rethans
    with Suhosin v0.9.33, Copyright (c) 2007-2012, by SektionEins GmbH
```

Comment: Call `ini_get('disable_functions');` just to make sure it's not disabled?

Comment: @Danack `ini_get('disable_functions')` outputs an empty string.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have specify `--enable-intl` when installing to use the bundled version of intl, or you can install it via PECL. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php

`apt-get install php5-intl` will also work.

Comment: You should mark this as the answer if it did help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add `php5-intl` to the list of things you install.

It looks like it's just not part of the core PHP5 release, even though it is an option to be included, similar to how `php-apc` is now a standard part of PHP, though you have to explicitly install it.

Comment: Installing `php5-intl` did it. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score -4):

Try in php.ini uncomment extension intl "extension = php_intl.dll", should be removed ";" before "extension", and then restart the server.

Comment: The OP is using Ubuntu, this won't help there.