# Class 'NumberFormatter' not found error in simple PHP program

Tags: php, numberformatter

I have a simple PHP program but I am encountering this error:

> Class 'NumberFormatter' not found

I have researched similar issues in Stackoverflow but honestly none gave a concrete solution.  Others suggest to upgrade the version of PHP, others un-comment a specific line in the php.ini file and none of those worked for me.

Below is my code:  I even used the suggested solution from [https://bugs.php.net](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68410) but it still doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
function writeMsg(){

$f = new \NumberFormatter("en", \NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);    

echo $f->format(1432);
}
writeMsg();
?>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what version of php are you using?  did you [enable/install the international extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003199/php-5-3-seems-to-be-missing-intl-extension-by-default)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Two things

1. You need PHP 5.3 or above.
2. You may not have the `php-intl` extension installed.

To check, run in your terminal:

```
php -m | grep intl
```

If there's no results, you'll need to install it which varies depending on your system and PHP Version

On a Mac for example, you can install it for PHP 5.6 by running:

```
brew install php56-intl
```

Make sure you restart your web server after you install!

EDIT for XAMPP:

If you're running XAMPP, then this is probably installed but not enabled.

1. Find your `php.ini` file -- path-to-your-xampp/php/php.ini -- and open it in an editor.
2. Search for `php_intl`. If you find `;extension=php_intl.dll`, then just remove the semi-colon from the front of the line -- this uncomments it.
3. Restart XAMPP!

Comment: I am a php newbie and just using xampp 3.2.1  PHP version is 5.5.27
HOw can I chack the extension not using the terminal?

Comment: In that case, it may be installed but not enabled.  You'll want to find your php.ini file.  Thats probably in your XAMPP application direction/php/php.ini.  Open that file in an editor and search for `php_intl`.  If you find `;extension=php_intl.dll`, then just remove the semi-colon from the front of the line -- this uncomments it.  Then restart XAMPP

Comment: Thank you solved my problem will accept the answer but I have a request. Please edit your answer to include the xampp approach to help others because there are similar questions here in stackoverflow but the accepted answers are not the correct ones.

Comment: @TwoThumbSticks glad it worked.  I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

As stated, you should have **PHP 5 >= 5.3.0** version and if you already uncomment `;extension=php_intl.dll` from **php.ini** file and still not working.. 
try to take a look at this answer. it really solve my problem.

[intl extension php_intl.dll with wamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372888/intl-extension-php-intl-dll-with-wamp/16372984#16372984)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
use \NumberFormatter;
```

The above code