# php extension intl is missing from your system magento

Tags: php

PHP Extensions Check.
1 missing PHP extensions.
showing when install magento 2 but i active this extension=php_intl.dll
i use xampp, restart it also not working

Comment: Restart the php engine (the http server most likely) after changing the configuration. Then check if the extension is actually loaded by means of phps `phpinto()` function. Also take a look at the http servers error log file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP 5.3 seems to be missing Intl extension by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003199/php-5-3-seems-to-be-missing-intl-extension-by-default)